Mathematical modelling of disease networks
I am trying to simulate a disease network in R. Basically, I have a network graph of 100 people. Connections represent friendships (i.e. neighbors). In this graph, all people start of healthy except 5 people. From here, neighbors have a certain probability of infecting their neighbors. Once someone is infected, they can either recover or die. People who recover have different probabilities of being reinfected compared to those who get infected the first time.
Here is the R Code I wrote in layers for a 15 day  simulation.
First, I define the graph and parameters:
library(igraph)
 set.seed(123)

num_nodes <- 100
num_days <- 15
initial_infected <- 5
infection_prob <- 0.3
recovery_prob <- 0.1
susceptible_again_prob <- 0.05
death_prob_healthy <- 0.01
death_prob_recovered <- 0.02
death_prob_infected <- 0.03

g <- sample_smallworld(dim=1, size=num_nodes, nei=5, p=0.05)

Next, I initialize - this code works by checking the state of each node in the simulation and considers which possible actions they can perform on each of their neighbors sequentially:
# Initialize node states (0=healthy_never_infected, 1=currently_infected, 2=healthy_previously_infected, 3=dead)
states <- rep(0, num_nodes)
states[sample(num_nodes, initial_infected)] <- 1

# Keep track of nodes that were ever infected
ever_infected <- rep(FALSE, num_nodes)
ever_infected[states == 1] <- TRUE

# Function to update states
update_states <- function(g, states, ever_infected, infection_prob, recovery_prob, susceptible_again_prob, 
                          death_prob_healthy, death_prob_recovered, death_prob_infected) {
    new_states <- states
    for (i in 1:vcount(g)) {
        if (states[i] == 0 || states[i] == 2) {  # Healthy (never infected or previously infected)
            if (ever_infected[i]) {
                if (runif(1) < death_prob_recovered) {
                    new_states[i] <- 3  # Die (previously infected)
                }
            } else {
                if (runif(1) < death_prob_healthy) {
                    new_states[i] <- 3  # Die (never infected)
                }
            }
        }
        else if (states[i] == 1) {  # Currently infected
            # Try to infect neighbors
            neighbors <- neighbors(g, i)
            for (j in neighbors) {
                if (states[j] == 0 || states[j] == 2) {  # If neighbor is healthy
                    if (runif(1) < infection_prob) {
                        new_states[j] <- 1  # Infect the neighbor
                        ever_infected[j] <- TRUE
                    }
                }
            }
            # Check for recovery or death
            r <- runif(1)
            if (r < death_prob_infected) {
                new_states[i] <- 3  # Die
            } else if (r < death_prob_infected + recovery_prob) {
                new_states[i] <- 2  # Recover (healthy_previously_infected)
            }
        }
        # State 3 (Dead) remains unchanged
    }
    return(list(new_states = new_states, ever_infected = ever_infected))
}

# Function to plot the network
plot_network <- function(g, states, day) {
    V(g)$color <- c("lightblue", "red", "lightgreen", "black")[states + 1]
    plot(g, vertex.size=8, vertex.label=NA, main=paste("Day", day))

}

After this, I plot:
par(mfrow=c(4,4))

results <- matrix(0, nrow=num_days+1, ncol=4)
colnames(results) <- c("HNI", "CI", "HPI", "D")

for (day in 0:num_days) {
    results[day+1,] <- table(factor(states, levels=0:3))
    plot_network(g, states, day)
    update_result <- update_states(g, states, ever_infected, infection_prob, recovery_prob, susceptible_again_prob, 
                                   death_prob_healthy, death_prob_recovered, death_prob_infected)
    states <- update_result$new_states
    ever_infected <- update_result$ever_infected
}

The code runs, but I can not paste the final visualization here for some reason.
What does everyone think?
